# Extracting numbers from 3 digit number in C++ is it possible w/o using arrays?

Tags: c++

Problem is : 
Write a function that as an input argument receives a three-digit positive number and as a result has to get the sum between the largest and the smallest number obtained by the same 3 digits divided by the median digit.
Example: input argument to function 438
The largest with the same digits is 843, the smallest is 348, so it should be calculated (843 + 348) / 4.

I have tried it and got the result ok but my code seems to complicated so iam asking is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int check(int x) {

    int a, b, c, biggestNum, smallestNum, medianNum;

    a = x / 100;
    b = (x / 10) % 10;
    c = x % 10;

    if (a > b && a > c && b > c) {

        biggestNum= a * 100 + b * 10 + c;
        smallestNum= c * 100 + b * 10 + a;
        medianNum= b;

    }
    else if (a > b && a > c && b < c) {

        biggestNum= a * 100 + c * 10 + b;
        smallestNum= b * 100 + c * 10 + a;
        medianNum= c;

    }
    else if (b > a && b > c && a < c) {

        biggestNum= b * 100 + c * 10 + a;
        smallestNum= a * 100 + c * 10 + b;
        medianNum= c;

    }
    else if (b > a && b > c && a > c) {

        biggestNum= b * 100 + a * 10 + c;
        smallestNum= c * 100 + a * 10 + b;
        medianNum= a;

    }
    else if (c > a && c > b && a > b) {

        biggestNum= c * 100 + a * 10 + b;
        smallestNum= b * 100 + a * 10 + c;
        medianNum= a;

    }
    else if (c > a && c > b && a < b) {

        biggestNum= c * 100 + b * 10 + a;
        smallestNum= a * 100 + b * 10 + c;
        medianNum= b;

    }   

    cout << "Smallest number is: " << smallestNum<< " ,biggest is: " << biggestNum << " and median is: " << medianNum<< "." << endl;

    return (biggestNum + smallestNum) / medianNum;
}


int main() {

    cout << "Enter one 3 digit positive number: ";
    int x;
    cin >> x;

    float result = check(x);
    cout << "The result is: " << result << "." << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd consider rearranging the values in `a`, `b`, and `c` so that `a` has the largest digit, `b` has the next largest digit, and `c` has the smallest digit. Then the three final values can be calculated directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted code can't really produce the right answer, considering that the result is calculated with integer arithmetic:

```
int check(int x)  // <- note the type of the returned value
{
    int biggestNum, smallestNum, medianNum;
    // ...
    return (biggestNum + smallestNum) / medianNum;  // <- This is an integer division
}

int main()
{
    int x; 
    // ...   
    float result = check(x);  // Now it's too late to get the right result
}
```

The logic also doesn't consider all the possible cases, as a matter of fact it ignores duplicated digits and the big `if else if` construct, lacking a default branch (a final unconditioned `else`), leaves those uninitialized variables undetermined so that the following operation gives a meaningless result.

Given the assignment restrictions, I'd write something like the following

```
#include <utility>

// The assignment is about 3-digit numbers, you should check that x is actually in
// the range [100, 999]. Note that one of the extremes is a special case.
// Well, both, actually.
double I_ve_no_idea_how_to_name_this(int x)
{
    constexpr int base = 10;
    int smallest = x % base;
    x /= base;
    int median = x % base;
    x /= base; 
    // Note that this "works" (extracting the third digit) even if
    // x isn't a 3-digit number. If you can assure the input is well
    // defined, you can simplify this.
    int biggest = x % base; 

    // Now we can sort the previous variables.
    using std::swap;
    if ( median < smallest ) {
        swap(median, smallest);
    }
    // Now I know that smallest <= median
    if ( biggest < median ) {
        swap(biggest, median);
    }
    // Now I know that median <= biggest
    // ...
    // Is that enough or am I missing something here?
    // Please think about it before running the code and test it.

    // Once the variables are sorted, the result is easily calculated
    return (biggest + smallest + base * (2 * median + base * (biggest + smallest)))
           / static_cast<double>(median);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I started this year as a part time CS student and the first programming languages that we started learning is C++ and html, is this normal with other Universities or .. i feel like we were better off learning JS or Python as a first language but that's just my opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
int check(int x) {
    int a,b,c,temp;
    a = x/100;
    b = (x/10)%10;
    c = x%10;
    if(b>a){
        temp=a;
        a=b;
        b=temp;
    }
    if(c>b){
        temp=b;
        b=c;
        c=temp;
    }
    if(b>a){
        temp=a;
        a=b;
        b=temp;
    }
    cout << "smallest: " << a+(b*10)+(c*100) << "\n";
    cout << "biggest: " << (a*100)+(b*10)+c << "\n";
    cout << "median: " << b << "\n";
    return (((a+c)*100)+(2*b*10)+(a+c))/b;
}
```

Comment: uses fewer variables (memory space) and is more concise.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use more descriptive variable names and should initialize each variable on definition. These two steps help greatly in squashing bugs in complex programs. I know this one isn't complex, but it's a good habit to have. Second, the standard library can help with finding the largest and smallest digit, which then makes the rest simple. So here's an example without any `if` statements.

Finally, [using namespace std; is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5699329) and should be avoided.

```
double check(int x)
{
    int a = x / 100;
    int b = (x / 10) % 10;
    int c = x % 10;
    int bigdigit = std::max({ a, b, c }); // find largest
    int smalldigit = std::min({ a, b, c }); //find smallest
    int middledigit = a + b + c - bigdigit - smalldigit; // sum of all digits minus largest and smallest gives the remaining one
    int biggest = smalldigit + middledigit * 10 + bigdigit * 100;
    int smallest = smalldigit * 100 + middledigit * 10 + bigdigit;
    std::cout << "biggest: " << biggest << '\n';
    std::cout << "smallest: " << smallest << '\n';
    std::cout << "median: " << middledigit << '\n';
    return (1.0 * biggest + 1.0 * smallest) / (1.0 * middledigit); --using double instead of int, as result could be fractional
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this check function.

```
int check(int x) {

    if(x >= 1000) x %= 1000;  //or return -1;

    //get digits
    int M = x/100;
    int C = (x/10)%10;
    int m = x%10;

    //unrolled bubble sort.
    if(M < C) swap(M,C);
    if(C < m) swap(C,m);
    if(M < C) swap(M,C);

    //simplified formula
    return ((m+M)*(101))/C + 20;

}

//derivation of formula
B = M*100 + C*10 + m;
s = m*100 + C*10 + M;
B+s = (m+M)*100 + C*20 + (m+M)
    = (m+M)*(100 + 1) + C*20
(B+s)/C = ((m+M)*(100 + 1) + C*20)/C
        = ((m+M)*(101))/C + 20
```